# IOS: size of view in iPad project with storyboard

Tags: ios, height, width, uistoryboard, xcode5

I start a new project in xcode 5 for iPad; then in the project target I set application only for landscape mode (right and left)
In storyboard I set my first view in landscape and when I run it's in landscape mode correctly.
I do a clean.
But if I do this log:

```
NSLog(@" width:%f", self.view.bounds.size.width);
NSLog(@" height:%f", self.view.bounds.size.height);
```

I also tried:

```
NSLog(@" width:%f", self.view.frame.size.width);
NSLog(@" height:%f", self.view.frame.size.height);
```

the result is width: 768
and height: 1024

but it's wrong because I have a landscape orientation.
What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you adding the NSLogs to viewDidLoad ? You have to let the view load completely before checking the dimensions. It should report correct dimensions in viewDidAppear.

Comment: oooooh I'm a stupid man... you're right, it's incredible but in viewdidappear I got the real size...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you limit your device orientations like this:
[image: Device settings]

I'm guessing you've done this, according to your question. Also make sure that your `UIViewController` classes override `supportedInterfaceOrientations` to return `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape`.

Comment: yeah I done this configuration and I add: - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
but nothing I have the width value size for height and viceversa

Comment: If I set a freeform for view, at example 2000 for width, the log print  ever the same values